# Why getContext function cannot be called on React JSX <canvas> object?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have the following code in a React.Component subclass

```
class SearchObject extends React.Component { 

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        var activateCanvas = <canvas></canvas>

        var activateDraw = () => {
            let ctx = activateCanvas.getContext('2d')
            //draw stuff
        }

        activateDraw()

        this.state = {
            activate: activateCanvas
        }
    }
...
```

the `activateCanvas.getContext('2d')` line returned error, saying getContext is not a function.
I wonder why activateCanvas here is not an Element object. Do I have to wait until the element is rendered and call something like document.getElementById() to use getContext()? Thanks

Comment: What you should actually do is create a ref, assign that ref to the canvas, and then use `ref.current.getContext('2d')` at the time of use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you need to render the react element you created first. Only then you can start referring to its DOM element. I would recommend using `ref` for that. Something like this should work:

```js
function App() {

  let ctx;
  var activateDraw = (ref) => {
    console.log('this is the canvas DOM element you want', ref)
    ctx = ref.getContext('2d')
    // draw stuff
  }
  var activateCanvas = (<canvas ref={(e) => activateDraw(e)}></canvas>)

  return (
    <div className="App">
      { activateCanvas /* don't forget to put the element into your render */}
      <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
         ....
```

Answer (score 1):

JSX doesn't actually return an `HTMLElement` it returns a render function, so you're basically trying to do this:

```js
const canvas = function(props, createElement) { /* render canvas*/}; // forgot the ordering of renderFn args... sue me
canvas.getContext('2d');
```

Personally, I use JSX with Vue, and in the case of Vue, if you wanted to do something like this, the short answer is yes, you would have to wait until it is rendered and then use the DOM to get access to the `HTMLElement` created by the JSX render function.

Hopefully someone with React expertise can confirm this is the case or provide a more refined answer tailored to your specific use-case with React.